# Android Google Maps V2: How to hide mapToolbar programmatically or how to invoke hide behavior of InfoWindow with mapToolbar?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, marker

When you click on a marker of Google Maps V2, the InfoWindow appears as well as the [Map Toolbar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_toolbar) slides in. I'd like to hide the InfoWindow and the mapToolbar when I click on the InfoWindow. Otherwise the user has to click anywhere beside the info window to close both but this is no good usability, because the info window is kind of big. I can do that by implementing **OnInfoWindowClickListener** and overriding **onInfoWindowClick()**

```
public class CustomInfoWindowClickListener implements OnInfoWindowClickListener
{
    public CustomInfoWindowClickListener()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
    {
        //Hiding the info window works, but it doesn't hide the toolbar as well
        marker.hideInfoWindow();

        //Not working as expected
        //googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

The method **setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean value);** only disables or enables the whole toolbar. Not what I want. There is no hide method or similar I actually expect.

What I actually want is to have the same behavior as on clicking beside the InfoWindow. That means hiding the InfoWindow and sliding out the mapToolbar. So either there is a way to slide out the mapToolbar (prefered solution) or I need to know how to simulate a click beside the InfoWindow. How can I achieve that?

**[UPDATE]**
I solved it by a workaround. I suppress the original InfoWindow and created my own one, so I bypassed the original Google Maps behaviour. (The `OnMarkerClickListener` in this example is used from the library [androidmapsextension](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions), `OnSnippetVisibilityListener` is just an interface the MainActivity implements to get informed when a marker is clicked so it can display my own snippet. `OnInfoWindowClickListener` is not used anymore.) The only cumbersome task is to calculate the right position of your snippet window (which is just a View) above the marker since you have to convert dp to pixel programmatically):

**MainActivity:**

```
private com.androidmapsextensions.GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new CustomMarkerClickListener(googleMap, this));
```

**CustomMarkerClickListener**

```
public class CustomMarkerClickListener implements OnMarkerClickListener
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Context context;
    private OnSnippetVisibilityListener onSnippetVisibilityListener;
    private final Logger logger = new Logger(CustomMarkerClickListener.class.getSimpleName());

    public CustomMarkerClickListener(GoogleMap map, Context context)
    {
        this.googleMap = map;
        this.context = context;
        onSnippetVisibilityListener = (OnSnippetVisibilityListener)context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
    {
        logger.log("onMarkerClick()", LogController.isLoggingEnabled(), Log.DEBUG);

        //suppress the real InfoWindow
        marker.hideInfoWindow();

        //some more code...

        onSnippetVisibilityListener.onSnippetVisible(true, marker);

        //It needs to return true to NOT execute the default behaviour
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Comment: @rion18 Yes, I bypassed it. I can tell you the solution when I'm home in 10 hours or so. (I think I wrote an own snippet handler because it was not able to display an AdMob ad inside the default one)

Comment: That'd be awesome, thanks

Comment: @rion18 I updated the question with my solution.

Comment: I'll try this to see if I can correctly hide (slide out) the Map toolbar... thanks!